# \usepackage{breakurl} and URL with ")" doesn't work

Tags: biblatex

see both files below: paper.bib and test.tex

1)

```
%\usepackage{breakurl}
```

=> it works but the url is too long - there should be a break

2)

```
\usepackage{breakurl}
```

=> works

=> but if there is a "(" or ")" (number should be different) in the url (see paper.bib), it doesnt work

```
error: Error: /syntaxerror in -file-
Operand stack:
   BU.L   (http://www.website.com/define.php?term=2)
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1930   1   3   %oparray_pop   1929   1   3   %oparray_pop   1913   1   3   %oparray_pop   1803   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1174/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:102/300(L)--   --dict:45/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

in the url i tried also `\)` - but doesnt work

what do i wrong :(?
can somebody solve the problem? tnx

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{breakurl} ------------- without % it doesnt work

\usepackage[hyperref,sortcites=false,style=authoryear,bibstyle=authoryear,minnames=1,maxnames=999,backend=bibtex,sorting=nyvt]{biblatex}
\bibliography{paper}

\begin{document}
  I hereby cite \cite{abc}.

\printbibliography
\printindex

\end{document}
```

**paper.bib**

```
@misc{abc,
  author = {{UB}},
  title = {{abc}},
  year = {2014},
  note = {\url{http://www.website.com/define.php?term=2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222)}},
}
```

Comment: is the closing paren really a part of the url?  in the "operand stack" report, the parentheses wrap around the entire url, so i don't think they should be included.

Comment: the original-link is:
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=:)

Comment: or is the only way http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=:%29

Comment: when i click on your first link, the box showing the url doesn't contain the final parenthesis.  on the other hand, the item being searched is the smiley `:)`.  with the `%029` it does show in the search url. so try that.

Comment: first link: ")" is not part of the stackexchange-a-href - so you have to copy the link WITH ")"

Comment: is there a solution without using %29?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`biblatex` has good control over breaking url's, *without* using the `breakurl` package.  In particular you can set `biburlnumpenalty` to a non-zero number to allow breaks after digits.  It is a counter, so use e.g. `\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{10}`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[hyperref,sortcites=false,style=authoryear,bibstyle=authoryear,minnames=1,maxnames=999,backend=bibtex,sorting=nyvt]{biblatex}
\bibliography{paper}

\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{10}

\begin{document}
  I hereby cite \cite{abc}.

\printbibliography
\printindex

\end{document}
```

See section 4.10.3 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) for other `biburl` pentalties that can be set.

Comment: andrew, tnx a lot for your comment